# Win 10 - Environment variables does not work unless I open the Environment Variables dialog (from system properties) and press "OK"

Tags: windows, windows-10, environment-variables

Environment variables do not work unless I open the Environment Variables dialog (from system properties) and press "OK".

EDIT: to clarify, not all paths were broken, later I've realized it was only with the particular entry where I've used the "%LOCALAPPDATA%" variable. After I do the "press ok" procedure, that variable gets replaced with the actual variable value.

Comment: What is not working?  What other way would you do it? You can see the complete path by using the PATH command in a command prompt or an Admin Command Prompt

Comment: Hey @John, thank you, seeing the PATH on CMD was a very helpful tip. I compared the value side by side (after reboot vs after "pressing ok"), and the difference was there was this one entry in which I've used the "%LOCALAPPDATA%" variable -- the "after pressing ok" version had this variable replaced with the correct value.

I moved that particular entry from System variables to User variables, with the "%LOCALAPPDATA%" variable replaced with actual value, and that fixed it. Create an answer based on this and I'll accept. Thanks!

Comment: You can create an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit PATH using the Advanced System Window (Environment Variables). You can also open an Admin Command prompt and use the PATH command to see the entire path. That may help you with seeing what you need to edit.

Replacing the particular entry from System variables to User variables may fix the issue for you.